# Google cloud unable to connect to the VM on port 22

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using Google Compute engine to host couple of sites but I resize the disk and then restarted the instance and now I am unable to connect both from gcs and putty. ( Connection Refused )

Serial console output:
http://pastebin.com/BZicx7JN

how can I troubleshoot this ?.

Comment: Before checking the console output I would wait for it to finish booting.

Comment: The output of the serial console does look incomplete. Did you follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) to resize the disk? Did you get any errors or did anything differently? I would suggest confirming that you have a valid file system and MBR record as explained [in this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#pdboot)

Comment: have you checked you firewall rules, i think you have delteed the rule that give access to to your instance at port 22.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? If so please consider posting a self-answer so the community can benefit.

Comment: Try by using different internet connection. Your ISP might not allowing port 22.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue with one of my GCP VM instance. My solution was:

1. Shut down the instance
2. Click 'Edit' for the instance
3. Under 'Custom Metadata' section, add 'startup-script' key, with value:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo ufw allow 22
```

4. Click 'Save'
5. Start the instance again, and SSH into it

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks.It works for me #! /bin/bash sudo ufw allow ssh

Comment: Thank you so much, its worked for me.

Comment: Can confirm that this still solved my exact problem in january 2021

Comment: Jun 2021 - Still works.

Comment: Didn't work for me, please provide other solution

Answer (score 4):

General recommendation to troubleshot this issue.

- Make sure the disk resize is done properly. Detailed steps are
  documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd).
- Confirm the instance has fully booted up. You can confirm this through VM [serial console output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/instances/getSerialPortOutput).
- Once the instance is booted confirm if ssh daemon is running. Serial console output will have information about ssh daemon. If ssh service is not running you can use [interactive serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) to start the service.
- Make sure you have [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking) configured in GCE network to allow ssh port.
- Make sure firewall on the instance(e.g. iptables) is allowing the ssh port. You can use interactive serial console to disable firewall on the VM, if required.

Comment: What information In VM serial console output can confirm the instance has fully booted up? What information In VM serial console output can confirm the daemon is running?