# GCP Connection Failed - SSH - We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, ufw

Since I received a email warning letter from google says "Action required: Critical problem with My First Project" saying my server has some abnormal outgoing activity , I tried to implemented ufw in my debian server.

For my ufw setting, I've done the following:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming 
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https
```

After I restart my server , I can't connect to my server with the error  "Connection Failed: We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Learn more about possible causes of this issue."

I tried the answer I found in this forum : [Google cloud unable to connect to the VM on port 22](https://serverfault.com/questions/823564/google-cloud-unable-to-connect-to-the-vm-on-port-22)

I followed the following instruction but it still not working:

1. Shut down the instance
2. Click 'Edit' for the instance
3. Under 'Custom Metadata' section, add 'startup-script' key, with value:

`#! /bin/bash`
`sudo ufw allow 22`

4. Click 'Save'

Can anyone help, I'll be appreciate!

[My GCP Custom Metadata setting picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hapLB.png)

Comment: While I was setting ufw , I'm sure I also set  "sudo ufw limit ssh". I don't know if this cause problem ?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to SSH before setting these OS FW rules. Restore UFW

`ufw reset`

`sudo ufw default deny incoming`

`sudo ufw default allow outgoing`

And then enable the SHH on the default port 22:

`sudo ufw allow 22`

`sudo ufw enable`

Be sure if you are using the default port number 22 or a different one. Follow these instructon if you are able to ssh without AFW.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh

Comment: Thanks for responding but the problem is I can't ssh to my server.
I've tried the following ways in to google troubleshooting-ssh page but no luck.
1. I tried gcloud to create default-allow-ssh 
2. I tried to use serial console to login but I haven't set password to my root account so I can't login.
3. I tried to add "/usr/sbin/ufw disable" to startup-script in Custom metadata and restart server many times but it seems the command is not executed so still not working.

Comment: Just add the commands `ufw reset` and `sudo ufw disable` to the start up script.

Comment: Remember that in the start up script you have admin rights, for login trough the serial console add an "user"
`#! /bin/bash
adduser username
echo 'username:password' | chpasswd
usermod -aG google-sudoers username`